# <br> tag breaking from top of table

Tags: html

In my form I am using a table and the `<br/>` tag not working. Here is my code:

```
<div class="contact_info">
                    <h2>career</h2>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="career">
                            <center>
                            <form>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                <td><td>Post Your Resume</td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>POST DETAIL:</td><td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>APPLIED IN:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="applied_in">DEGREE<input type="checkbox" name="applied_in">DIPLOMA</td>
                                </tr><br/>
                                <tr style="padding-top:100px;">
                                <td>DEPARTMENT:</td><td><input type="text" name="department" placeholder="Enter Department" size="36"></td><br/>
                                </tr><br/>
                                <tr>
                                <td>APPLIED FOR THE POST OF:</td><td><input type="text" name="app_post" placeholder="Enter Post To Work With" size="36"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>PERSONAL DETAIL:</td><td><textarea rows="3" cols="40"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION:</td><td><textarea rows="3" cols="40"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>DETAILS FOR EXPERIENCE:</td><td><textarea rows="3" cols="40"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>RESUME:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" value="Choose File"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </form>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

In this code I am using `<br/>` in two different places but it is always breaking the line from top.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mn8gdds/)

Comment: why did you open 2 `<TD>` in the line `<td><td>Post Your Resume</td></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put 
 tag inside  or  tag. 
 will not work inside  or  tag.

```
<td>Name:<br></td>
```

will work

```
 <tr><td>Name:</td><br></tr>
```

won't work.

Answer (score 4):

`<br>` tags cannot be direct descendants of the `<table>` or `<tr>` tags, they must be placed within a `<td>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all `<br>` from your code, there are not able for tables, and use padding.

Example:

```
<div class="contact_info">
                    <h2>career</h2>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="career">
                            <center>
                            <form>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                <td><td>Post Your Resume</td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>POST DETAIL:</td><td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rowspace">
                                <td>APPLIED IN:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="applied_in">DEGREE<input type="checkbox" name="applied_in">DIPLOMA</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="rowspace">
                                <td>DEPARTMENT:</td><td><input type="text" name="department" placeholder="Enter Department" size="36"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>APPLIED FOR THE POST OF:</td><td><input type="text" name="app_post" placeholder="Enter Post To Work With" size="36"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>PERSONAL DETAIL:</td><td><textarea rows="3" cols="40"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION:</td><td><textarea rows="3" cols="40"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>DETAILS FOR EXPERIENCE:</td><td><textarea rows="3" cols="40"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>RESUME:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" value="Choose File"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </form>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

and class

```
.rowspace td { padding-bottom: 1em; vertical-align:top; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using.

```
<td>Name:<br></td>
```

but,best way to do it using CSS.